# Play and Pause function

Tags: ios, media-player, avaudioplayer

I have a soundboard app that plays sound and is supposed to play music and if you click the button then it pauses but it doesn't pause it only stops the music.
And once the music finishes the button stays selected.

My code is;

```
 - (IBAction)aint:(id)sender {
UIButton *aint = (UIButton *)sender;

aint.selected = !aint.selected;

if(aint.selected)
{
    // Play
    NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"mp3"];
    theAudio2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2] error:NULL];
    theAudio2.delegate = self;
    theAudio2.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [theAudio2 play];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"-" forKey:@"music"];
}
else
{
    // Pause
    [theAudio2 pause];
 }
}
```

And I have theAudio2 and AVAudioPlayer declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will work as expected -

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"mp3"];
      theAudio2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2] error:NULL];
      theAudio2.delegate = self;
      theAudio2.numberOfLoops = 0;
    }

 - (IBAction)aint:(id)sender 
    {
      UIButton *aint = (UIButton *)sender;
      aint.selected = !aint.selected;

      if(aint.selected)
      {
        // Play
        [theAudio2 play];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"-" forKey:@"music"];
      }
      else
      {
        // Pause
        [theAudio2 pause];
      }
    }

 - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
    {
       playerBtn.selected = NO;
    }
```

Comment: The `playerBtn` was were `aint` was and it wont work saying `use of undeclared identifier aint`.

Comment: Declare PlayerBtn in your .h file and connect it to ur UIButton in Xib file then you can make it work.

Comment: What do you mean by mail id?